# How configure JBoss to reject HTTP request on HTTPS port

Tags: ssl, jboss

I have configured JBoss with HTTPS connector only. Now I have problem, that in case I'm using HTTP request to HTTPS connector, it returns page with one ASCII character, instead of some error page, for example 505 or something else what can user inform, about invalid request.

There is no used Apache nor any other web server, where some rules for URL rewriting could apply. Also often used change in web.xml with `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` tag do not solve this problem, as there must be HTTP request, which is then redirected to HTTPS based on "redirectPort" param in connector configuration and in this case there is not plan to use any other port and it is not possible to combine HTTP and HTTPS listener together on one port.

Is there some way how to configure SSL listener, that way, that it refuse HTTP request, or automatically change to HTTPS?

JBoss 5.1.0

Comment: HTTPS status 505 indicates that you are using HTTPS but the wrong version. You can't get an HTTP status code over an HTTPS connection unless both ends are speaking HTTPS. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Ok than... some another way for notify or reject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser uses HTTP to talk to server, but on the server side is the security layer (around the HTTP) and it wants to do a SSL/TLS handshake. So the communication fails because client doesn't know about the security on the other side.

The client (browser) receives error message (binary data) from server. The client doesn't know what to do with them, so it presents them to a user as a web page content.

[RFC-5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2) states:

> Error handling in the TLS Handshake protocol is very simple.  When an
> error is detected, the detecting party sends a message to the other
> party.  Upon transmission or receipt of a fatal alert message, both
> parties immediately close the connection.

Undertow - a new web server in WildFly - is able to do [HTTP Upgrade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/1.1_Upgrade_header#Use_with_TLS). But I'm not sure if the upgrade to SSL/TLS is already supported. Nevertheless, the problem with this scenario could be on the browser side.